# Разные виды глаголов в главном и придаточном предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допустимо ли употребление разных времён в главном и придаточном предложении в данном случае: "Я молча смотрел на город, но крик моей души разрушал тишину, что укутала мою комнату"?

Comment: А где вы тут разные времена нашли? Везде прошедшее. Может, вы имели в виду разные виды глагола?

Comment: Да, я имел в виду разные виды глагола всё-таки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, такое написание допустимо. Когда Вы переходите от общего предложения к придаточному, Вы смещаете "фокус" повествования, переходите как бы внутрь ситуации и имеете право для создания нужного впечатления не только использовать разные виды глагола, но и даже разные времена.

Главное тут — не перемудрить, не напутать. В Вашем примере всё нормально. Тишина УЖЕ КОГДА-ТО ДО ЭТОГО укутала комнату **и так и осталась**, но крик её в ОПИСЫВАЕМЫЙ МОМЕНТ разрушает.

А вот если бы Вы употребили слово **окутывала**, к тексту возникли бы вопросы. Можно было бы прочесть предложение так, что тишина когда-то окутывала комнату, потом, возможно, перестала, куда-то пошла по своим тишинским делам, но тут её настиг крик души и воздал по заслугам, чтобы неповадно было. Я, конечно, утрирую. Но это специально, чтобы Вы почувствовали разницу. Окутывала — другое слово. Оно не привязано к конкретному моменту. Когда она окутывала? В тот самый момент? Часом ранее? На год раньше? Когда-то до нашей эры? Это неопределённость. Она не критична. Можно было бы написать и так, но раз уж вопрос у Вас возник, то ответ таков: Ваш пример стилистически правильнее.

А вот к "но" можно придраться. Внятного противопоставления там нет. Я бы рекомендовал заменить на "а". При желании можно подробнее расписать, почему "а" предпочтительнее "но" в Вашем случае, но это уже тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: @Артём Луговой , позвольте поинтересоваться, с какой целью Вы избирательно изменили прописную букву на строчную в слове "вы" в одних случаях и оставили в других?

Comment: Не хотел ничего плохого, просто заметил, что Вы пишете "Вы" с большой, а "ваш" с маленькой вначале, а потом единообразие нарушается и "Ваш" тоже становится таким. Я не знал, как лучше, по-быстрому сделал единообразно с началом. Простите, если получилось неудачно.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой давайте сведём уже к какому-то общему знаменателю)) Или везде прописную, или строчную. На Ваш выбор.

Comment: Давайте на Ваш. Сделайте, как считаете правильным, пожалуйста. ;)